# How safe is running the command "youtube-dl -U" to update youtube-dl?

Tags: windows-10, youtube-dl

I've read the manual and searched their GitHub. I can't find any information whatsoever about what this command does other than "downloads the latest binary and replaces the existing one which it somehow determines the location for".

```
youtube-dl -U
```

But does it also check the checksum/signature to make sure it's not been compromised? I find it to be a massive chore to keep manually downloading youtube-dl from their site and then uploading it to VirusTotal and then manually replacing the binary.

And even if it does the signature/checksum checking, it still won't be safe if the developer's machine has been compromised, or whatever mechanism they use to distribute the binaries.

Comment: Did you try to find the documentation or man pages, etc. to see if it indicated anything regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it looks fairly safe assuming you trust them in the first place.

> does it also check the checksum/signature to make sure it's not been compromised?

Yes.  If you look at the source of [update.py](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/update.py) on github it downloads a file *versions.json* and checks its signature.

```
    UPDATE_URL = 'https://yt-dl.org/update/'
    VERSION_URL = UPDATE_URL + 'LATEST_VERSION'
    JSON_URL = UPDATE_URL + 'versions.json'
    UPDATES_RSA_KEY = (0x9d60ee4d8f805312fdb15a62f87b95bd66177b91df176765d13514a0f1754bcd2057295c5b6f1d35daa6742c3ffc9a82d3e118861c207995a8031e151d863c9927e304576bc80692bc8e094896fcf11b66f3e29e04e3a71e9a11558558acea1840aec37fc396fb6b65dc81a1c4144e03bd1c011de62e3f1357b327d08426fe93, 65537)
.
.       
    if 'signature' not in versions_info:
        to_screen('ERROR: the versions file is not signed or corrupted. Aborting.')
        return
    signature = versions_info['signature']
    del versions_info['signature']
    if not rsa_verify(json.dumps(versions_info, sort_keys=True).encode('utf-8'), signature, UPDATES_RSA_KEY):
        to_screen('ERROR: the versions file signature is invalid. Aborting.')
        return
```

This file contains the SHA of the .exe (and other resease types) which it checks against what it downloads :

[image: versions.json]

```
    newcontent_hash = hashlib.sha256(newcontent).hexdigest()
    if newcontent_hash != version['exe'][1]:
        to_screen('ERROR: the downloaded file hash does not match. Aborting.')
        return
```

> And even if it does the signature/checksum checking, it still won't be safe if the developer's machine has been compromised

If they lose their keys as well then yes but that is true of everything.

Someone would have to hack their server and also make copy of *versions.json* which is **signed with their keys** containing a different hash value for the .exe and possibly a different download location.